# Ruby joining error

Tags: ruby

I am trying to unpack some variables then have them joined when passed to the def this is what i'm trying, but it errors.

```
class Try
  def test
    @name = "bob"
    @password = "password"
    self.send(@name,@password)
  end

  def send(*data)
    print data #prints orginal data
    print ":".join(data) #errors
  end
end
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For future reference, don't just say "it errors". Describe the error. Include the error.

Comment: A Pythonista, perhaps?

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry, will do.

Comment: Don't name a class "Try", which is an action or verb. Name classes after something. Your methods are your actions. `class Tree` and `Tree.new.grow`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are people who have tried to answer your question. If this helped you, you can tell the community so by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) that was most useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

Here you should do as below using [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
class Try
        def test
            @name = "bob"
            @password = "password"
            self.send(@name,@password)
        end
        def send(*data)
            print data.join(":")
        end
end
Try.new.test
# >> bob:password
```

The `join` is for Array instances. It is not a String instance method. See below:

```
Array.instance_methods.include?(:join) # => true
String.instance_methods.include?(:join) # => false
```

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps you are confusing the built-in function `join` of a Python string with the `join` method of the Ruby `Array` class.

From `help(":".join)` in Python:

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
>   iterable.  The separator between elements is S.

And from the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join) on Ruby's `Array`:

> Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a string,
>   separated by the given separator.

So you see, the Python `join` built-in function concatenates the strings of the given list argument, while in Ruby the `Array#join` method will convert the elements into their `String` equivalents, and then concatenate them using the separator argument.

Hope this clears up the confusion between Python's `join` and Ruby's `Array#join`!